# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error) not in gzip format

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sencha-touch, sass, compass-sass

I am developing a Sencha touch 2 application. I have been following the "[Styling the user interface of a Sencha Touch application](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/styling-user-interface-sencha-touch-application)" tutorial on theming of secha touch applications.

It requires me to install Ruby, Compass and SASS. 
I installed Ruby using the installer from rubyinstaller.org.

On executing the following command, I get the expected result which confirms correct installation:

```
C:\>ruby -v

ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10) [i386-mingw32]
```

Current source is up to date:

```
C:\>gem sources

** CURRENT SOURCES **

http://rubygems.org/
```

Next, since I am behind a proxy, I used the following command to install HAML/Compass:

```
C:\>gem install -p [proxy:port] compass

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
not in gzip format**
```

Can someone help me? I found solutions such as system update, gem sources update, but everything is up to date on my system.

---

Edit:

```
C:\>gem install compass
```

works perfectly fine on my private system. When I try the same command from my workplace I need to use the proxy as mentioned above and that results in an error.

Comment: `C:\>gem install compass` works fine on my private system. But at my workplace, I need to use a proxy in my command : `C:\>gem install -p [proxy:port] compass` which throws the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume the ERROR occurs since the web sense at my workplace blocks these downloads.

**Solution**: I downloaded the required gems: **chunky_png, fssm, compass, sass, haml** etc.. directly from http://rubygems.org/gems and placed these gems in my local directory.

After this I tried `gem install compass`. This first searches your local directory. On finding the required gems,  installation takes place. Does not require connection to the ruby website.

Note: Run the command from the path where the gems are located

eg: I have placed the gems in C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems

So I run the following command :

`C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>gem install compass`

Comment: Very Good solution for all type of gems which show `ERROR: While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)`

Comment: I had the similar issue of access controlled for gem files and I have resolved it by @senchaDev's approach for installing sass and compass. Thanks a ton.

Comment: This did not work for me. I actually had to download the `.gem` file manually and then `sudo gem install --local mailfactory-1.4.0.gem`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, it worked on my own private laptop, but failed while using a virtual server at work (running Ubuntu 12.10) that used a proxy.

Following the suggestion I found [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2973966), from the command line I defined:

```
export HTTPS_PROXY=proxy-address:proxy-port-number

export HTTP_PROXY=proxy-address:proxy-port-number
```

and then my *gem install package* worked fine.