# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error) not in gzip format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am trying to execute the command "gem update --system" in my windows command prompt and it shows the error as

```
Updating rubygems-update
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format
```

When I try to install any gems also with gem install gemname command it is showing the same error message.

Please help. I am executing the command in windows.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same issue with `ruby version 1.9.3-p551` downloaded with `rbenv` on macOS High Sierra and looking for multiple solutions online but none of them work.

However, I notice that when I run

```
gem sources
```

The result is

```
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://rubygems.org/
```

When I run with ruby version 2.1.9, the result is

```
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

https://rubygems.org/
```

So I remove the `http` source and use `https`

```
gem sources -r http://rubygems.org/
gem sources -a https://rubygems.org/
```

It works! So I doubt that the `http` server has problem dealing with `gzip` encoding. Hope this help for everyone using old ruby version like `1.9.3`.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who is reviving some old app:

I tried downloading GEM from rubygems.org and installing with `gem install gemname.gem` but it still ended with same err:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format
```

Adding explicitly `--local` helped.

```
gem install --local ~/Downloads/gemname-X.Y.gem
```

Not going to investigate more, but it was with:

```
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.5
RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2013-12-22 patchlevel 375) [i686-darwin18.7.0]
in ASDF environment..with custom compiled openssl 1.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this at your workplace or school that might be blocking the downloads?

The solution in this question: [ERROR: While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error) not in gzip format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684137/error-while-executing-gem-zlibgzipfileerror-not-in-gzip-format)

Was to download the gems directly from  http://rubygems.org/gems, then run the install commands, since it looks locally first.

Comment: Thought the same...I was wrong. `gem install ~/Downloads/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.3.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format`. Interesting is that `gem install ~/Downloads/rack-1.0.1.gem
Successfully installed rack-1.0.1` went thru. :)