# rubygems.rb:550:in `initialize': not in gzip format (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

when i try to run the command 'bundle install' or installing particular gem then ot in gzip format (Zlib::GzipFile::Error) occurs.
i have done googling and find some of the answers
like removing cache ,bundle packages but all fail in my case

i am using rails 3.2.11 and ruby 1.8.7

the code of rubygems line arround 500 is

```
def self.gunzip(data)
  require 'stringio'
  require 'zlib'
  data = StringIO.new data

  Zlib::GzipReader.new(data).read
end

##
# Zlib::GzipWriter wrapper that zips +data+.

def self.gzip(data)
  require 'stringio'
  require 'zlib'
  zipped = StringIO.new

  Zlib::GzipWriter.wrap zipped do |io| io.write data end

  zipped.string
end
```

while error in console is

Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:550:in `initialize': not in gzip format (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:550:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:550:in `gunzip'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:177:in `fetch_path'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:270:in `load_specs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:243:in `list'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:239:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:239:in `list'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:104:in `fetch_specs'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:117:in `fetch_all_remote_specs'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:262:in `fetch_all_remote_specs'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:116:in `specs'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:235:in `remote_specs'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:235:in `each'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:235:in `remote_specs'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:163:in `fetch_specs'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:67:in `specs'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `index'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `each'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `index'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `index'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `resolve'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:109:in `resolve_remotely!'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:83:in `run'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:320:in `update'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `__send__'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20
    from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:19
```

Hope this information will be enough for providing me the right way for solution

Comment: @mguymon can you provide me the solution or a way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059175/not-in-gzip-format-error